# How can I place a GLTF model behind a stencil mask in three.js?

Tags: three.js, webgl, portal, gltf

I'm using a stencil mask in Three.js to create a portal effect.
It works correctly on meshes when I can control the material.
However, when I load a gltf model with the model's material I cannot get it to hide outside the stencil mask.

[See this example screenshot here with the desired effect with a cube mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgeOk.png)

[Screenshot of GLTF model unable to hide outside the stencil mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL0fc.png)

```
    // Stencil rules to make material hide 
   material.stencilWrite = true;
   material.stencilFunc =  THREE.EqualStencilFunc;
   material.stencilRef =  1;
   material.stencilFuncMask =  0xFF;
   material.stencilFail =  THREE.KeepStencilOp;
   material.stencilZFail =  THREE.KeepStencilOp;
   material.stencilZPass =  THREE.ReplaceStencilOp;
```

Here is a codepen with both the mesh and the gltf model:
https://codepen.io/jattfield/pen/GRMzRjw

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

Example of the model hiding correctly behind the stencil:
https://codepen.io/jattfield/pen/jOaEZmJ

[Model hiding correctly behind the stencil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z3lX.png)

```
skinnedMesh.material.stencilFunc = THREE.EqualStencilFunc;
skinnedMesh.material.stencilFuncMask =  0xFF;
skinnedMesh.material.stencilZPass =  THREE.ReplaceStencilOp;
skinnedMesh.material.stencilZPass =  THREE.ReplaceStencilOp;
skinnedMesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
insideGroup.add(gltf.scene);
gltf.scene.renderOrder = 3; // This was the KEY !!!!
```

The `gltf.scene` **HAS** to be rendered after the stencil mask. I had used a `renderOrder` on the "insideGroup" I was placing it in, but it seems this was not enough. Interestingly, when I attempt to place models with multiple meshes, each mesh also has to be given a specific `renderOrder`.

I can find very little documentation on this kind of stuff. I have what I need working, but if there is anybody out there also working with models and stencil masks I'd love to see it. Thanks.